# where does source code located on Azure web hosting?

Tags: .net, azure

I have a website which was built on.NET MVC Framework. which is hosted on Azure. now I need to change little HTML codes but I have no idea where does source code located I tried to find but not succeed. can anyone guide me where actually code files located?

Comment: Vague question. How did you deploy? Web Apps? VM? Cloud Services (web/worker role)?  How did you get your code there in the first place? As written, really no way to answer. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: it is web application. sorry I forget to mention i did not deploy it. the person who builds it for me deploy it and i can't connect with him.

Comment: i just found out it is deployed to virtual machine  can u guide me how to access source code ?

Comment: If it is a VM how could we know? connect to the VM, try to start IIS manager and take a look there, it might show the location of the website.

Comment: You'll need to talk with the person who deployed it. There's absolutely no way for any of us to know how your source code is maintained. (and if you're not using some type of version control, you might have much bigger issues...)

Answer (score 0):

> I just found out it is deployed to virtual machine can u guide me how to access source code ?

Here are detail steps.

1. Remote login to your VM.
2. Open command window by press Win + R. In the command window, type 'inetmgr' to open IIS.

[image]

3. We can find all the sites which hosted in the IIS under sites folder. If you want to view the source code of a website, you could right click your the website and click 'Explore' context menu.

[image]